# Refresh parent visualforce page after standard action is successfully completed

Tags: visualforce, lightning

I have a visualforce page with following code:

```
<apex:outputlink value="{!URLFOR($Action.Custom_Object__c.Edit, id_of_object,[retURL=URLFOR($Page.The_page)])}" >Edit</apex:outputlink>
```

When I click on the link in Lightning, a pop-up window appears for edit object. The window is standard action. If I close it the visualforce page does not refresh.

What do I need to do for refresh visualforce page?

Answer (score 0):

In your visualforce page use a javaScript method to call it in apex:outputlink on oncomplete event and render apex:outputlink based on ui themes. Like Them4d for Lightning, Theme3 for classic ui and Theme4t for salesforce1 mob app.

```
Function refresh(){
sforce.one.back(true);
}
```

call it on oncomplete of apex:outputlink: as

```
<apex:outputlink value="{!URLFOR($Action.Custom_Object__c.Edit, id_of_object,[retURL=URLFOR($Page.The_page)])}" oncomplete="return refresh()" rendered="{!$User.UITheme == 'Theme4d'}">Edit</apex:outputlink>
```

It will give you a refreshed view in lightning mode.

> Remember to write another block of code for rendering the same output
>   link in classic other wise you will not be able to see the outputLink
>   in classic mode.

```
    <apex:outputlink value="{!URLFOR($Action.Custom_Object__c.Edit, id_of_object,[retURL=URLFOR($Page.The_page)])}" oncomplete="return refresh()" rendered="{!$User.UITheme == 'Theme3'}">Edit</apex:outputlink>
```

Reference:-

- https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce1.meta/salesforce1/salesforce1_dev_jsapi_sforce_one.htm
- https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_global_useruitheme.htm

If it still does not give you a refreshed view, then add another method to redirect to edited record id using this:-

**navigateToSObject(​recordId​[, view]) or navigateToURL(​url​[, isredirect])**